# Non blocking WebSocket Server with POCO C++

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I'm trying to build a WebSocket server with POCO.
My Server should send data to the client and all the time within a time intervall. And when the client sends some data, the sever should manipulate the data it send to the client.

My `handleRequest` method within my `WebSocketRequestHandler`:

```
void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
{
    WebSocket ws(request, response);
    char buffer[1024];
    int flags = 0;
    int n = 0;

    do {
        // recieving message
        n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
                   // ... do stuff with the message

        // sending message
        char* msg = (char *) "Message from server"; // actually manipulated, when message recieved
        n = sizeof(msg);
        ws.sendFrame(msg, strlen(msg), WebSocket::FRAME_TEXT);

        sleep(1);  // time intervall sending messages
    } while (n > 0 || (flags & WebSocket::FRAME_OP_BITMASK) != WebSocket::FRAME_OP_CLOSE);
}
```

The problem is, that the method get stucked in `we.recieveFrame()` until it gets a frame.
So how can i solve this, that `receiveFrame()` is not blocking the loop.
Is the a better way to solve this complete problem?

Thanks.

Comment: 'Non blocking'......sleep(1);

Comment: sure.. you're right :-) @MartinJames, but actually its not even getting so far, when client isn't sending a message.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. If you do not get a frame, you would not have the message, so what would you send?

Comment: when a client connects, a base64 encoded String is send to the client, which is rendered as an image in the browser. That's the reason, the server has to send continously to the client. If the client send's a message to the server, like 'blackWhite', the server is doing some processing and changes the string, that is send to the browser. And so on...

Comment: I managed a similar situation on a Poco C++ library based solution by setting a receive timeout with: ws.setReceiveTimeout(timeout);

Answer (score 1):

You should set a receive timeout.

```
ws.setReceiveTimeout(timeout);
```

So, you will get a `Poco::TimeoutException` each timeout microseconds and you can do all you need, included send data by that websocket.

```
ws.setReceiveTimeout(1000000);//a second
do{
  try{
    int n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
    //your code to manipulate the buffer
  }
  catch(Poco::TimeoutException&){
    ....
  }
  //your code to execute each second and/or after receive a frame
} while (condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::thread` or `pthread` and call the blocking function in the thread's function